# Spreadsheet with conditional dropdown based on options from another sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, drop-down-menu

I have a destination sheet where in Col "B" there are a list of "Companies", in Col "K" I would to choose, with a dropdown, the "Address" available (of that specific "Company") taken from another sheet, located in col B and J.

How to do this with a script?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15g_3TMmVufKZogCbO3SUWBUp3iwc21nQgPBw6_GWXQQ/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to put the data validation rules to the column "K2:K" in the sheet `destination`.
- You want to create the rules by retrieving the values from the columns "B" and "J" in the sheet `source`.

For this, how about this answer?

#### Flow:

1. Retrieve values from the both sheets.
2. Create an object for creating the rules.
3. Create the rules.
4. Put the rules to the column "K" in the sheet `destination`.

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  // 1. Retrieve values from the both sheets.
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const src = ss.getSheetByName("source");
  const dst = ss.getSheetByName("destination");
  const srcValues = src.getRange("A2:J" + src.getLastRow()).getValues();
  const dstValues = dst.getRange("B2:B" + dst.getLastRow()).getValues();

  // 2. Create an object for creating the rules.
  const obj = srcValues.reduce((o, [a,b,,,,,,,,j]) => Object.assign(o, {[a]: [b, j]}), {});

  // 3. Create the rules.
  const rules = dstValues.map(([e]) => ([SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(obj[e]).build()]));

  // 4. Put the rules to the column "K" in the sheet `destination`.
  dst.getRange("K2:K" + dst.getLastRow()).setDataValidations(rules);
}
```

#### References:

- [newDataValidation()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#newdatavalidation)
- [setDataValidations()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setDataValidations(DataValidation))

### Added 1:

For your 3 additional questions in your replying, I answer as follows.

- Q1: If in future I would to retrieve the values from further columns in the sheet source. How to edit the script?

  - A1: In this case, please modify `[a,b,,,,,,,,j]`. Now, `a`, `b` and `j` are `Company`, `Address options 1` and `Address options 2`, respectively.
- Q2: To have the sheets update with the script, you suggest me to activate a trigger?

  - A2. I cannot understand what you want to do.
- Q3:  If I put a value in the col "B" (destination) that is not present in col "A" (source), the script not works. I need this.

  - A3: Please modify above script as follows.
  - From

    ```
    - const rules = dstValues.map(([e]) => ([SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(obj[e]).build()]));
    ```
  - To

    ```
    const rules = dstValues.map(([e]) => ([obj[e] ? SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(obj[e]).build() : null]));
    ```

### Added 2:

> The question 2, I explain. Naturally when I run the script the dropdown are populated, but if I add a new company, I must to run again the script and so on... to avoid this, how can I do?

For above your additional 2nd question, the sample script is as follows. In this case, when the column "B" of the sheet of `destination` is edited, the script is run. In this case, the simple trigger can be used.

#### Sample script:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const range = e.range;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (range.getColumn() != 2 || sheet.getSheetName() != "destination") return;

  // 1. Retrieve values from the both sheets.
  const ss = e.source;
  const src = ss.getSheetByName("source");
  const dst = ss.getSheetByName("destination");
  const srcValues = src.getRange("A2:J" + src.getLastRow()).getValues();
  const dstValues = dst.getRange("B2:B" + dst.getLastRow()).getValues();

  // 2. Create an object for creating the rules.
  const obj = srcValues.reduce((o, [a,b,,,,,,,,j]) => Object.assign(o, {[a]: [b, j]}), {});

  // 3. Create the rules.
  const rules = dstValues.map(([e]) => ([obj[e] ? SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(obj[e]).build() : null]));

  // 4. Put the rules to the column "K" in the sheet `destination`.
  dst.getRange("K2:K" + dst.getLastRow()).setDataValidations(rules);
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212923/discussion-on-answer-by-tanaike-spreadsheet-with-conditional-dropdown-based-on-o).